# Removing SCCM Offline Servicing schedules without a next run time

Tags: sccm-2012

I've noticed in our OfflineServicingMgr.log file there are a lot of lines like the following:

```
This Schedule with ID 16777256 does not have a next run time
```

Is this a problem?
How can I remove these old schedules?

Comment: As @kce mentioned below, the Schedule Updates Wizard doesn't allow for recurrence. However the scheduled task is still in the system somewhere. The list of Schedules with a next run time is getting longer each time I schedule an update.  So how can I get rid of these entries and stop the pollution of the OfflineServicingMgr.log?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have scheduled your Offline Image Serving (i.e., applying Software Updates to an offline image using DISM) in such a way as that schedule does not have another possible run time. Looking a the Wizard it appears that a Custom Schedule has no option for re-occurance.

The Custom Scheduling is designed primarily with the goal of ensuring that you do not inadvertently trigger an network intensive content update of your image to all of your distribution points and less about automating the process of doing Offline Image Processing.

[image: ImageServicingScheduling]

Comment: That is correct, I am using the Wizard but there is no option for recurrence. Is there a better way to update my image?

Comment: @P.Turpie I don't think you can run re-occurring Offline Image Servicing. It is a one time shot - either "now" or at a custom scheduled time.

Comment: I don't think there would be much point to repeating the task as you have to select which updates to install. Reinstalling the same updates would be pointless. However it would be nice to have a way to automatically update my image with **all** the latest updates on a regular basis though.

Comment: What I don't understand is why those Scheduled tasks are being kept in the system somewhere. Twice a day our OfflineServicingMgr.log is flooded with 33 lines of `This Schedule with ID 16777xxxx does not have a next run time`. It doesn't make sense to keep them around.

Comment: @P.Turpie "It doesn't make sense" Many things in SCCM don't make sense. If you want to dig deeper I'd suggest a support call but there's no recourse that I can see. The product is working "as designed".